# hasMany relation not working in laravel

Tags: laravel

My cart model has:

```
public function product() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

My Product Model has:

```
public function cart() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cart');
}
```

My database looks like:

**Cart Table:**

[image]

**Product Table:**

[image]

My cart migration contains:

```
$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```

My controller contains:

```
public function index()
{
   if(Auth::check())       
   {
      $user = Auth::user();
      $cart = Cart::where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
      return view('products.cart')->withCart($cart);
   }
   else {
     return view('products.cart');
   }
}
```

**It checks if user is logged in then it get details of all cart where user id matches with current user. This is working.**

But when I go to product.cart page I try:

```
@foreach($cart->product as $p)
  {{dd($p->name)}}
@endforeach
```

**I get error:**

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$product (View: D:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\resources\views\products\cart.blade.php)
```

**Can you tell me how to get value from products table with this relationship.**

Thanks!

**Edit:**

After trying different method I got:

Cart Model:

```
public function product() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id','product_id');
    }
```

Cart Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::check())       
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $cart = Cart::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();

            return view('products.cart')->withCart($cart);
        }
        else {
            return view('products.cart');
        }
    }
```

**Now I am able to get the first product that matches with id.**

**Is there a way to get all product that matches**

Comment: Storing the products in a cart table is not really a good way to go. I would store the contents of the cart in the session.

Comment: The inverse of `hasMany` is `belongsTo`. You need to use that. Refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships). My guess is, it should be _product belongs to a cart_.

Comment: @linuxartisan after changing to `belongsTo` getting same error

Comment: Actually this is a structure you'll regret sooner or later. But you should be using hasManyThough (users has many products through cart). Let me know if you need help to set this up. Cheers.

Comment: @HudsonPereira please help me set this up. as I cant move forward until this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use `$...->get()` returns collection. Use `first()` instead.

```
$cart = Cart::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
if($cart) {
    return view('products.cart')->withCart($cart);
} else {
    abort(404);
}
```

Comment: I am getting error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column products.cart_id in where clause (SQL: select * from products where products.cart_id = 1 and products.cart_id is not null)`

Comment: Hmm, you should many to many instead of hasMany. Or keep your old code and replace hasMany with one to one (hasOne). I will use many to many (instead of using carts table, use orders table directly to store orders with new column `is_paid` or `is_accepted` )

Answer (score 0):

Go to User's model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Cart');
}
```

Now, in your controller you'll fetch the logged user's cart. And pass it to the view. e.g

```
return view('cart.show', ['cart' => Auth::user()->cart]);
```

Then your foreach will work like expected.

PS: You may have to specify ids on the hasManyThrough relation if you're not using the convention naming for database tables. i.e Model singular (Product) to pluralized tables (products).

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following code.

In your Cart Model

```
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','id','product_id')
}
```

In your Controller

```
$cart = Cart::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
```

Comment: I am getting error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`product_id` = 1 limit 1)

Answer (score 0):

In your Cart model you need to specify relation for products:

```
public function products(){
  //return $this->hasMany('App\Product'); should be changed to 
    return return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','carts_products', 'cart_id', 'product_id'); //  see link to tutorial below.
}
```

With this relation you can enable lazy loading of products when you get Cart object for user to achieve this in your controller you need:

```
public function index()
{
   if(Auth::check())       
   {
      $user = Auth::user();
      $cart = Cart::with('products')->where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
       //we get cart via first() as we need single instance of cart not an array of carts, 
       //even there's only one cart per user get() will return an array of one item
       // with('products') lazyloads linked products to cart as you get cart instance
      return view('products.cart')->with('cart',$cart);
   }
   else {
     return view('products.cart');
   }
}
```

Later in your view you'll be able to iterate over lazy loaded products array like:

```
@foreach($cart->products as $p)
 {{dd($p->name)}}
@endforeach
```

Think of creating relations between models in terms of how you'll access them in future, most of the time you don't need to overspecify all relations between objects, as only some of them you'll realy use in code.
Hope it'll help you.

**EDIT**

change relation type to belongsToMany and it should work, as your Cart has many Products. You still need to get one single Cart instance with first() method byt related Products will be loaded as you need.

**Important:**

Look at this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel as you need to change your database schema to achieve this. Currently your schema allows you to have only one product per cart. Look into this example where they create picnics to bears table `bears_picnics` - in your case you'll have products to carts table `carts_products` walk through tutorial in you case  `cart` is `bear`  and `picnics` are `products`.

Example `carts_products` schema:

```
   Schema::create('carts_products', function(Blueprint $table)
   {
       $table->increments('id');

       $table->integer('cart_id'); // the id of cart
       $table->integer('product_id'); // the id of product in cart

       $table->timestamps();
   });
```

remove `product_id` field from you cart schema as it's useless in such case. if you need cascade deletion specify it on `carts_products` table.

Happy codding! Thank you for a good question:) making us to make a research deeper.

Comment: I am getting error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.cart_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`cart_id` in (1))